# "Ant not recognized as an internal or external command" - Develop Spring application tutorial

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ant

I know that this question is is asked before but I tried lot of solutions, no one helped me.

I'm new to JEE applications and I started with this Spring Framework tutorial and I'm stuck on beginning, can't setup Ant and Tomcat. I followed those setups (http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html) to setup ant and Tomcat, before that I installed Tomcat 9.0 and setup it in Eclipse.

This is structure of my application and build.properties file, all other files are same as in tutorial. Tomcat Server is started, but can't figure out why am I getting ant not recognized error. 
[image]

Can somebody help me please? Thank you!

EDIT: I also installed ant and added it to System variables:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is using Ant to build and assumes that Ant is already installed and added in the classpath. You need to install Ant and defining ANT_HOME as well adding ANT_HOME/bin to classpath; before compiling and deploying our code. You can download Ant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I installed atn also and add it to System variables (I edited my question and attached one more image) and also tried to add ant path to build.properties instead of Tomcat path, but still I have same issue. :-/

Comment: I followed this (https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/) tutorial for ant installation and did every step and at the end when I tried just to check is it ant installed I got same mistake that ant not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :)

I followed this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arTLYV3_po4) tutorial for ant installation. Then I had issue "taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask cannot be found" and resolved it by changing

```
<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

to

```
<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"> 
  <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/> 
 </taskdef>
```

Now build works finally. :) This probably should be changed in Spring tutorial.